# Need OKTA API for testing connection purpose or workaround for testing connection?

Tags: connection, okta, okta-api

Does anyone know any sort of API to test the connection with OKTA IDP is succeed or failed?

If connection is **successful** then we can carry on with other OKTA operation.

If connection is **failed** then perform necessary operation to fix it as per failure error message.

If there isn't any API is there any **workaround** to achieve it? If yes, can you help us?

Thanks in advance,

Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

The method that you use for testing for a successful connection to Okta's REST API will depend on the programming language and method that your programming language uses to make HTTP requests.

Generally, you should configure your HTTP requests with a timeout and test for valid HTTP status codes. Your code should be configured to handle timed out HTTP requests or HTTP requests that don't return a status code.

In addition to handling HTTP and/or TCP/IP related errors, you should also handle the various errors that the Okta API will return. A list of errors codes is available here: http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/error_codes.html